# Kotlin Coroutines, cant set info to recyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I'm new to Coroutines, and I cant use it properly.My guess is that my code is setting list to recyclerView before Coroutine task is done so the list is empty. My question is how can I ensure that first of all data base information is read and then set to recyclerView.

```
private fun setView() {
    var info = getList().toMutableList()

    recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity())
    adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(info, MainActivity())
    recyclerview.adapter = adapter
}

private fun getList() : List<Post> {
    var list : List<Post> = listOf()
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        var info = db.userDao().getAll()
        list.forEach { Log.d("my", it.title) }
    }

    return list
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are returning "list", even when coroutine has not finished yet. Are you using viewModel? A great solution would be:

On your viewModel, create a liveData to store your list

```
class myViewModel: ViewModel() {
     val myList = mutableLiveDataOf<List<Post>>
}
```

On your viewModel create a function that only calls the coroutine:

```
fun getList() : List<Post> {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        var info = db.userDao().getAll()
        lmyList.postValue(info) // Here you are updating you list 
    }

    return list
}
```

Observe your list from activity/fragment:

```
   class myFrag: Fragment() {
     /*some code*/
     myViewModel.myList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{ list ->
          if(!list.isNullOrEmpty()){
               /* Here you'll have your list and can set it on the adapter*/
          }
     })

   }
```

you'll need:
LiveData API - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata
Coroutines on viewmodel - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

Comment: Thanks for help mate. I found simple solution to this tho and now i feel stupid ;d
Instead of calling getlist in setView,
I called the setView function in getList and passed list as a parameter after getting the list and it did the job.
Thanks for your answer.